# Problem with Donut Tutorial Part 4: Icing has weird edge

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, extrude, solidify-modifier

Thank you for your advice so far :) Here is the file:
[image]

---

I've tried to find an answer to my problem with the icing part of the famous Donut Tutorial, but failed completely.

There are lots of people having problem with extruding to achieve the icing drops, but none that look like my problem. Somehow, the drops snap to the donut, but when I extrude and show the solidify modifier, the new vertices create an edge (see picture).

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Did you come across the same problem or maybe can tell me, what I need to do differently?
Any hint is highly appreciated.
(Oh, I'm using the current version of Blender (3.5).)

Thanks very much!

Best wishes,
Frau K.

[image]

Comment: Hi. With all due respect. You will greatly improve your chances of getting some help if you would attach your .blend file to your question by uploading it to: https://blend-exchange.com/ That way someone doesn't have to go to another site and look at a video to try and probably guess at what might be wrong with your model.

Comment: Hi, Frau K .. I think curious is right, this is a case for a share. Hard to say, without it.

Comment: Thank you two for your kind advice :) I've uploaded the file and added the link to the question.

Answer (score 0):

All the faces in your icing are doubled. It looks as though, at some stage, an extrusion has been dropped in place (with a right-click), or a 0-depth *Solidify* has been applied.

Some general tools for diagnosis, with all modifiers' visibility switched off, possibly in an isolated view, (<kbd>Numpad /</kbd> in Object Mode) :

- Jiggle some vertices around (with <kbd>G</kbd>) and see what's behind them
- <kbd>H</kbd> hide some faces, and see what's behind those..

re-introduce modifiers, one at a time.

Fix, in this case: Edit Mode, all selected,  <kbd>M</kbd> Merge > By Distance

Comment: BTW, the rim of your icing will be rounder if the Solidify is _above_ the Subdiv, in your modifier stack.